# Displaying text in middle of div?

Tags: css, css-float

Here is the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HddpMhbsVFBoVjCFQY1D?p=preview)

How can I put dates and number in middle of div?

I prefer not using exact pixel values, are there better ways?

Comment: You have been around long enough and yet don't know how to ask a question?

Comment: Please explain your comment, I definitely want to learn how can I be more elaborative and clear

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you, could you please tell me what headline I missed in that?

Comment: You could shorten up your demo, take out the stuff that doesn't matter, put it in something like jsfiddle.  Also with this short of a question you could post some code snippets.  You're putting a lot of work on people answering the questions (if they want to make a good answer) here that could have been done yourself.

Comment: -1: the dates and numbers seem to be in the middle of the div, for me. (Fx 22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.started
{
  text-align:center;
}

.started span {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

And remove your various margin-left: x em; from your

classes .started span {} , .days-left span, and .today span {}

Answer (score 1):

I can't get your demo to load for me without crashing my browser, but:

You can use percentages (top 50%, left 50%) You may have to tweak the percentages depending on the size of what you want placed in said div.

There's also making the left and right margins "auto", which will match them automatically regardless of the content width.

(Try using jsfiddle for demos. It hasn't ever caused my browser to crash.)

Comment: The demo wasn't working for me either! :c - also from personal experience `auto` may not work properly for vertical centering depending on the browser. EDIT: nvm i just reread your post and noticed that you specified right and left margins